# How do I Override a Iterable<interface> return type method into Iterable<? extends interface> return type method

Tags: java, oop, generics, overriding, decorator

I have an interface that I need to implement. It looks something like this:

```
public interface SimulationState {
    ...
    public Iterable<VehicleStatus> getVehicleStatuses();
}
```

I am trying to extend the interface into some sort of a decorator interface as the following:

```
public interface SimulationStateDec<V extends VehicleStatus> extends SimulationState {
    ...
    @Override
    public Iterable<V> getVehicleStatuses();
}
```

**OR**

```
public interface SimulationStateDec<V extends VehicleStatus> extends SimulationState {
    ...
    @Override
    public Iterable<? extends VehicleStatus> getVehicleStatuses();
}
```

Here's the concrete class I'm implementing the interface at:

```
public class WareHouseState implements SimulationState {
    ...       
    @Override
    public Iterable<VehicleStatus> getVehicleStatuses() {
    return this.vStatuses;
   }
}
```

I am implementing the **VehicleStatus** interface at a class named **VehicleState** so i could return the implemented **VehicleState**
though the Iterable in my concrete class

So at a class in my project I am calling the `getVehicleStatuses()` method
and I am obligated to cast every element to **VehicleState** as the following:

```
public class Gate {
    ...
    private ArrayList<VehicleThread> vehicles;

    public Gate(WareHouse wareHouse, GatePriority priority) {
        ...
        this.vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        wareHouseState.getVehicleStatuses().forEach(v -> vehicles.add(new VehicleThread((VehicleState) v, wareHouse)));
        sortSameTimeArrivalBy(priority);

    }
}
```

I know I am doing something wrong here, I was wondering if that way of implementation is allowed.
Compiler tells me to change the method in the implemented interface and it's not applicable for my application has to work on a different framework.

I need to return a variety of concrete types that implements the same interface without having to cast every element.

Comment: This could be a good question but you need to provide more details, such as a [mcve] showing how you intend to use the interface.  As it stands now the question is too vague.

Comment: Read this to understand the problem: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: yes after reading it It makes sense, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should use it, since X< A> is not substitutable by X< B > even though A extends B, to simply put Iterable< VehicleStatus> is not replaceable by Iterable< V> where V extends VehicleStatus.Hence, the error that you are changing method return type while overriding

```
   public class VehicleStatus{

   }

   public interface SimulationState {
      Iterable<? extends VehicleStatus> getVehicleStatuses();
   }

   public interface SimulationStateDec<V extends VehicleStatus> extends SimulationState {
     @Override
     public Iterable<V> getVehicleStatuses();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because when overriding you can only narrow down the return type, and neither `Iterable<V>` nor `Iterable<? extends VehicleStatus>` are subtypes of `Iterable<VehicleStatus>`.

In Java 8 you could perhaps add the new method without overriding and implement the old one as a default (or use abstract class in previous versions):

```
public interface SimulationStateDec<V extends VehicleStatus> extends SimulationState {
    ...
    Iterable<V> getVehicleStatusesDec();

    default Iterable<VehicleStatus> getVehicleStatuses() {
        return (Iterable<VehicleStatus>) getVehicleStatusesDec();
    }
}
```

This should be safe because `Iterable<T>` doesn't have any methods which take `T` as argument: it "should" be covariant except Java doesn't support that; doing the same with e.g. `List` is a bad idea!